# Boolean input not passed correctly to reusable workflow

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have an invoking and a called (reusable) workflow.

Here is the input of the reusable one:

```
      stg_image_build:
        description: whether to build the staging image
        required: true
        type: boolean
        default: false
```

Here is the relevant part of the calling workflow

```
      push_to_stg:
        description: "Build and push image to staging registry"
        type: boolean
        default: false
        required: true

...


  build-and-push-image:
    uses: path/to/reusable/workflow.yaml@master
    with:
      stg_image_build: ${{ inputs.push_to_stg }}
```

This fails as follows:

```
The template is not valid. .github/workflows/calling.yaml (Line: 72, Col: 24): Unexpected type of value '', expected type: Boolean.
```

The error refers to this line:

```
stg_image_build: ${{ inputs.push_to_stg }}
```

Why?

Comment: I made a test with [this workflow](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester61.yml) calling this [reusable](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester62.yml) and everything seems to work fine with this implementation: [runs](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/actions/workflows/workflow-tester61.yml). It may be related to another part of the workflow syntax (despite the message).

Comment: Thank you for getting into the trouble of reproducing this; yes this does not make any sense...I have removed all other steps (just in case there is something else interfering and I am still getting the error...)

Comment: Feel free to share the whole workflows implementation for me to test it here as well 

Comment: I am having the same issue... @pkaramol have you find out was was going on?

Answer (score 2):

Booleans behave differently for `workflow_dispatch` and `workflow_call`, which is a misimplementation by github team and discussed in length here:

https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/1483

The essence is that booleans sometimes actually behave as strings and have to be treated as such.

Edit: Looking at this again, it might also be because you have to use `github.event.inputs.push_to_stg` instead of `inputs.push_to_stg` in the last line of your caller script.